# How to get replace degree symbol in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of strings where an element looks like '69.3  °F' I want to strip out the '°F' of the entire list so I can convert it into a float.

I've tried:

```
myTemps = myTemps.replace("°F", "")

myTemps = myTemps.replace(u"°F", "")
```

and 
    myTemps = [w.replace('°F','') for w in myTemps]

```
myTemps = [w.replace(u'°F','') for w in myTemps]
```

I keep getting back

```
'list' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

any advice as to what I am doing wrong?

When I print MyTemps I get

```
['69.9  °F'], ['70.3  °F'], ['70.0  °F'], ['69.5  °F'],
```

myTemps is a list made up of lists

Comment: Whatever `myTemps` is, the elements in it are lists, not strings.

Comment: Right thats why I did list comprehension

Comment: Yes, the elements _within_ `myTemps`, an iterable, probably a list or something, are lists themselves. Do `print(myTemps)` and add the output to your question, please? :)

Answer (score 1):

Right, if your `myTemps` is a list of lists of strings and you want a list of floats,

```
>>> temps = [['69.9  °F'], ['70.3  °F'], ['70.0  °F'], ['69.5  °F']]
>>> [float(l[0].replace('°F', '').strip()) for l in temps]
[69.9, 70.3, 70.0, 69.5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `map` function in Python to replace the degrees symbol on all elements within the list.

```py
def ReplaceDegrees(temperature):
    return temperature.replace("°F", "")

myTemps = ["12°F", "56°F", "112°F"]
myTemps = list(map(ReplaceDegrees, myTemps))
```

For more on the map function see https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_map.asp or https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map

Comment: This is more or less what OP is doing, but they have a list of 1-lists of strings so this will break equally. Also, a list comprehension tends to be considered more Pythonic than `list(map(...))`.